# Symfony 2 / Oracle Querybuilder result is case sensitive

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a strange behavior with a query result in Symfony 2.
I have data like this in an Oracle Database, in this exact order :

1. BU 4 2015
2. bU 2
3. BU C
4. BU S
5. BU 4 2014

***notice, the lower case in the second data***

I Just want to display this list by alphabetical order, without any case sensitive support.
The wanted result :

```
- BU C
- bU 2
- BU 4 2014
- BU 4 2015
- BU S
```

Now, here is the Querybuilder, made with Symfony 2.5.12 :

```
 $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
 $queryBuilder->orderBy('e.name');
```

But the query, show my list in this order :

```
- BU C
- BU 4 2014
- BU 4 2015
- BU S
- bU 2
```

- When i play the query displayed in symfony 2 profiler in my Oracle database client, i get the wanted result.
- When i dump the query builder result, I get the wrong order list.

I manage to solve my problem by this

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
$queryBuilder
    ->select(e)
    ->addSelect('UPPER(e.name) as HIDDEN name')
    ->orderBy('name');
```

So, I just want to know why I get this strange behavior with the querybuilder ?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know much about Oracle, but it might be problem with collation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your "wanted result" is not actually in alphabetical order. A case-insensitive sort would yield the following order:

```
bU 2
BU 4 2014
BU 4 2015
BU C
BU S
```

Second of all, the way to do a case-insensitive sort with Oracle SQL is to use `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` on the column(s) you want to sort by, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM e
ORDER BY UPPER(e.name);
```

Finally, the way to do a case-insensitive sort with Doctrine QueryBuilder is exactly how you have done it: by adding `UPPER(e.name) as HIDDEN name` and then sorting by that field.

There is no strange behavior by QueryBuilder in this example.